# Highcharts gauge with two yAxis and related size

Tags: highcharts

i have a gauge chart with two y axis. The second axis should have a size of 50% of the first axis. I know the offset property, but there i only can set numbers as a value. Is there a way to do that?

Here is a fiddle. The inner blue circle should be the half size of the outer one.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhpbc176/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'gauge',
                alignTicks: false,
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBackgroundImage: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false
            },

            title: {
                text: null
            },

            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },

            pane: {
                startAngle: -70,
                endAngle: 70,
                background: null
            },

            plotOptions: {
                gauge: {
                    dial: {
                        baseWidth: 2,
                        baseLength: '100%',
                        radius: '100%',
                        rearLength: 0
                    },
                    pivot: {
                        radius: 5
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },

            yAxis: [ {
                min: -300,
                max: 500,
                tickPositions: [-300, -200, -100, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                lineColor: '#933',
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                tickLength: 0,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                labels: {
                    distance: 12,
                },
                offset: 0,
                plotBands: [{
                    from: -300,
                    to: 2,
                    thickness: 15,
                    color: '#55BF3B'
                }, {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 202,
                    thickness: 15,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: {x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 0},
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#55BF3B'],
                            [1, '#DDDF0D']
                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    from: 200,
                    to: 500,
                    thickness: 15,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: {x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 0},
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#DDDF0D'],
                            [1, '#ff0000']
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                min: -200,
                max: 200,
                lineColor: '#339',
                tickColor: '#339',
                minorTickColor: '#339',
                offset: -100,
                lineWidth: 2,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tickLength: 0,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                endOnTick: false
            }],

            series: [{
                data: [250]
            }]
        });
```

Comment: If you gauge chart has a specific size you should be able to math the correct offset.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way which comes to my mind is divide chart container by 4, then you will achive 50% of chart height.

```
offset: (function(){
    return -1 * ($('#container').height()/4);
})(),
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jhpbc176/1/